# What are the generic functions defined by the standard?

Tags: common-lisp, clos

In Common Lisp there are a few generic functions defined by the standard, for instance functions to manipulate sequences.

However looking at Graham's book *ANSI Common Lisp* and Steele's book *Common Lisp – The language* at the relevant chapters, I could not find any list of the generic functions defined in the standard.

What are the generic functions defined by the standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently see no better way than to go through the pages of the [CLHS Master Index](http://clhs.lisp.se/Front/X_Master.htm) and grep for "Generic Function".

Applying this suggestion a local copy of the HyperSpec using the script

```
% sed -n -e '
/Standard Generic Function/{
 s/.*Standard Generic Function *//
 s|</A>||
 p
}' X_Mast_*.htm | sort -u
```

yielded the following list

```
(SETF CLASS-NAME)
ADD-METHOD
ALLOCATE-INSTANCE
CHANGE-CLASS
CLASS-NAME
COMPUTE-APPLICABLE-METHODS
DESCRIBE-OBJECT
DOCUMENTATION, (SETF DOCUMENTATION)
FIND-METHOD
FUNCTION-KEYWORDS
INITIALIZE-INSTANCE
MAKE-INSTANCE
MAKE-INSTANCES-OBSOLETE
MAKE-LOAD-FORM
METHOD-QUALIFIERS
NO-APPLICABLE-METHOD
NO-NEXT-METHOD
PRINT-OBJECT
REINITIALIZE-INSTANCE
REMOVE-METHOD
SHARED-INITIALIZE
SLOT-MISSING
SLOT-UNBOUND
UPDATE-INSTANCE-FOR-DIFFERENT-CLASS
UPDATE-INSTANCE-FOR-REDEFINED-CLASS
```

Answer (score 4):

## The question you asked

Functions that manipulate [sequences](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/17_.htm)
are *not* [`generic-function`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_generi.htm)s.
They are listed in the section [17.3 The Sequences
Dictionary](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/c_sequen.htm).

All [`symbol`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_symbol.htm)s specified by the
standard are listed in the section [1.9 Symbols in the COMMON-LISP
Package](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/01_i.htm).

A *partial* list of standardized
[generic functions](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/07_f.htm) can be
found in section [7.7 The Objects
Dictionary](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/c_object.htm) (e.g.,
[`print-object`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_pr_obj.htm) is listed in
section [22.4 The Printer Dictionary](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/c_printe.htm)).

## The question you might have meant to ask

Finding existing Lisp functionality should not be hard using
[`apropos`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apropo.htm).
Once you see a plausibly looking symbol, use
[`describe`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_descri.htm) to find out what it
actually does.

Remember that most implementations offer more that the standard specifies.
You can do something like this:

```
(dolist (pack (package-use-list "COMMON-LISP-USER"))
  (format t "~S~%" pack)
  (do-external-symbols (s pack)
    (when (and (fboundp s)
               (typep (fdefinition s) 'generic-function))
      (format t "  ~S~%" s))))
```

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I was not clear enough, I am actually trying to find a list of classes and methods defined by the standard. Since methods are not necessarily associated to a single class I focused on the methods. IIUC classes and methods defined in the standard are centred around the object system itself, leaving an essentially white page for the programmer wanting to use them.

Comment: You might want to check Common Lisp's metaobject protocol (MOP).

Comment: @PauloMadeira: MOP has not been standardized by the ANSI.

Comment: I know, but the op wants some sort of "white pages", and most implementations follow the MOP to some extent, with projects available to level some differences (closer-mop, cl-mop, etc.).  And if the op is interested in good OOP practices in Common Lisp, I dare say the op should check CLIM 2.